# Quero adicionar uma tecla no meu código JavaScript no p5.js

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho essa duas funções, porém, o meu problema é na moveRacketE(), eu estou fazendo um ping pong, só que eu queria fazer para duas pessoas jogarem, e não eu jogar contra o computador, como eu poderia adicionar a tecla W para subir, e a tecla S para descer na função moveRacketE()?

```
function moveRacket() {
  if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
     yRacket -= 10;
  }
  if(keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    yRacket += 10;
  }
}

function moveRacketE() {
  if(keyIsDown(event.key == 87)) {
     yRacket -= 10;
  }
  if(keyIsDown(event.key == 83)) {
    yRacket += 10;
  }
```

Comment: Tente usar `if(keyIsDown(87))` e `if(keyIsDown(83))`

Comment: Usei, porém, ele está movimentando a minha raquete, e eu gostaria de movimentar a raquete inimiga

Comment: Consegui arrumar, eu tinha que mudar o yRacket para yRacketE, que foi a variável que eu criei, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lendo a [documentação do p5](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown), o problema é que você está enviando um `boolean`, comparando `event.key == 87`, quando na verdade você só tem que comparar o valor direto usando os [códigos de teclas do p5](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyCode).

Tente substituir o seu código pelo seguinte:

```
function moveRacketE() {
    if(keyIsDown(87)) { //W
       yRacket -= 10;
    }
    if(keyIsDown(83)) { //S
       yRacket += 10;
    }
}
```